# Why is Chrome displaying color emoji characters but printing black & white?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, printing, colors, unicode

The following characters (for example):

> (U+1F31E Sun With Face) 
>  (U+1F319 Crescent Moon)

Are displayed like this in Chrome:

[image]

But print like this (all drivers, including PDF) (in preview and in real print):

[image]

Why isn't Chrome printing these characters as displayed, and how do I make it do that?

My expectation is that media-specific CSS aside, Chrome would print the same characters that it shows.

I have a document that I made in HTML that has these characters in it, and I would really like them to be printed with the colors they're displayed with. Every other colored element on the page prints fine. The font choice does not seem to matter.

Chrome: Version 95.0.4638.69 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Windows: Windows 10 Pro Version 10.0.19043 Build 19043 (64-bit)

Comment: Randomly started happening for me today where Chrome displays them in Black and White normally. Looks like a recent Chrome update messed it up. I'm on Version 96.0.4664.45 (Official Build) (64-bit). Same Windows version as you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've revisited this a bit, and found a couple interesting things, most notably that the [latest build of *Chromium*](https://download-chromium.appspot.com/) (949708 at the time of this writing) does *not* have this issue.

As far as Chrome 96.0.4664.93 (latest at time of writing) goes, the issue just seems to have something to do with Segoe UI Emoji not being rendered in color in the print output. I confirmed that Chrome uses that font for all emoji characters, it's just the colors aren't used in the print renderer.

It does seem to be just a color issue, as on closer inspection, the edge outlines in the printed glyphs are a perfect match for the edge outlines in the displayed glyphs -- i.e. they look like the same glyphs, minus color.

Here's a test document ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wuarpx0b/)):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Print Output Test</title>
    <style>
      .default-font { }
      .emoji-font { font-family: 'Segoe UI Emoji'; }
      .other-font { font-family: 'Times New Roman'; }
      .generic-font { font-family: sans-serif; }      
      .color-test { color: red; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="default-font">The  and the .</div>
    <div class="emoji-font">The  and the .</div>
    <div class="other-font">The  and the .</div>
    <div class="generic-font">The  and the .</div>
    <div class="default-font color-test">The  and the .</div>
    <div class="emoji-font color-test">The  and the .</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And a comparison of Google Chrome vs base Chromium (on my Win 10 machine):

| Browser | Displayed | Print Preview | PDF Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Google Chrome† | [image: chromedisplay] | [image: chromeprint] | [image: chromepdf] |
| Chromium | [image: crdisp] | [image: crprint] | [image: crpdf] |

And here's some info from the inspector (which, btw, also renders the colored glyphs) - it's identical for both browsers:

| Browser | Inspector |
| --- | --- |
| Both | [image: inspector] |

---

So, based on the fact that it works in Chromium but not in Chrome, what this all leads me to believe is that...

- Either it was an issue that was noticed then fixed in Chromium but hasn't made it into Chrome yet for whatever reason, or...
- It's always behaved correctly and is a bug that was introduced in Chrome.

The only way to know which one it was is to either try older versions of the browsers (which I'm not going to do) or try to find an official bug report + fix somewhere (which I was unable to do).

So I'm just going to file it as a bug report in Chrome and I guess cross my fingers.

In the mean time a workaround, if you need this to work, is to grab Chromium and print with that, rather than Chrome.

---

<sub>*† Unrelated note: The reds are inconsistent in the screenshots. Both browsers have color profile quirks but I've got Chrome set to sRGB mode and Chromium at its default. That's why the two browsers aren't identical in that respect.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome team just decided to make 'em a bit more colourful. Copy 'em to a text editor that does not support images (e.g. Notepad) and it'll show the boring black/white versions. Printing them as they appear in Chrome would probably require saving the page as an image/pdf (multiple plugins exist that can do that) and printing that. For example [GoFullPage](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gofullpage-full-page-scre/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl) and [Full Page Screenshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screenshot/glgomjpomoahpeekneidkinhcfjnnhmb).

Comment: But if chrome can substitute images for glyphs inline like that and render them sensibly to display devices, and can lay out and render everything else on the page (including images) to print devices, surely it must be able to also render substitute images to print devices? Like, I could substitute those characters for inline images manually and it would print those correctly, I imagine.

Comment: @JasonC I agree. It surely is able to. But it doesn't. Not sure why.

Comment: Btw saving the page as a PDF shows the same issue. Also I can't really take a screenshot or anything, the page is designed to responsively fit the selected print page size, orientation, and device specific margins, and it also uses physical units that must print to the correct scale. All of that is possible in other formats and programs I guess, but it's super duper easy and convenient in html. So it'd be nice if there was a way to have it not print surprise character differences. :(

Comment: Perhaps I can summon the mighty @Ramhound

Comment: Interestingly, the issue does *not* appear on latest *Chromium* build. ‍♂️